# how to create a table based on the value from checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
$conn=get_dbconnect();
$sql="select name from states";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);//odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='state' value='".$row['name']."' /> ".$row['name'];  
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="btntest">

<script>
    function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
        var selchbox=[];
        var inpfields = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;
        for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
            if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
        }
        return selchbox;
    }
 </script>
```

This is the code to fetch value in checkbox. using this checkbox I want to create a table with 3 fields .. lets say name,class,roll.no.. can anyone help me.

Comment: describe what type should have each of the needed fields in the new table

Comment: you should describe what to you mean by "table". I assume you want to create table in database? or you want to genereate some kind of HTML table?

Comment: i want to generate html table